# ubuntu 14.04. libiberty not found after install

Tags: 14.04, configure

I'm trying to run a configure script which fails because it can't find a library called libiberty. So, I used apt like that: `sudo apt-get install libiberty-dev` which completed successfully. The configure script still can't find libiberty though. What can be done?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You should look for it in platform directories.
For me all it took was adding following configure option:

`--with-libiberty=/usr/lib/i386-linux-gnu/`

How I figured it out was simple find from command line:

`find /usr/ -iname '*iberty*'`

Which returned some header files and `/usr/lib/i386-linux-gnu/libiberty.a`.